# Shape size not equal to the table cell size and fit the text inside the shape

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, shapes, google-slides

Trying to insert a shape equal to the table cell size.

I created the shape using `InsertShape()` and copied the height of row (possibly height of cell), width of column (possibly width of cell) to the shape.

**Problem :**

1. size of shape is not equal to cell size in height and width.
2. The text inside the shape is going out of shape, text of shape should be auto fit, while the text of the cell fits inside the cell.

I can't say how `.getRow().getMinimumHeight()` works.

Text length not fixed. It could be like a long paragraph.

Limitation of Google Apps Script :

Table Cell - Google Apps Script can't get the width and height of each cell

Google Apps Script:

```
let activePresentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()
let selection = activePresentation.getSelection()
let pageElements = selection.getPageElementRange().getPageElements()

//get table Left, table Top of each table under the pageElement object
var tableLeft = pageElements[0].asTable().getLeft(),
    tableTop = pageElements[0].asTable().getTop();

var cellTop = tableTop;       //cell top possible equal to table top   
var cellLeft = tableLeft;    //cell top possible equal to table Left 

//get the row height and column width
var rowHeight = pageElements[0].asTable().getRow(0).getMinimumHeight();
var columnWidth = pageElements[0].asTable().getColumn(0).getWidth();

//get the internal text of cell
var cellText = pageElements[0].asTable().getCell(0, 0).getText().asString()

//insert shape equal to the table cell size
var shape_t = selection.getCurrentPage()
                   .insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.RECTANGLE, 
                                         cellLeft+200, 
                                         cellTop, 
                                         columnWidth, 
                                         rowHeight);

//set the cell text insde the Shape 
shape_t.getText().setText(cellText);
```

Here you can see the demo https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/10nupvk-2BZDSV6-gPn_n2LkrUtkCxot7qr_jcZGBHqw/edit?usp=sharing

**Full Script :**
https://pastebin.com/CrV3qHwG

**Replicate Issue**
Paste above mentioned https://pastebin.com/CrV3qHwG script in Google Script Editor,
Add a table with 1 row and 1 column, obviously it will be only one cell.
Select the table and then run the script by clicking on "Create Shape" from the "Test So" menu.

**Image shows problem and expected result in quick view**

[image: Image shows problem and expected result in quick view]

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So can I ask you about the detail flow for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike Here you can see the demo https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/10nupvk-2BZDSV6-gPn_n2LkrUtkCxot7qr_jcZGBHqw/edit?usp=sharing

Full Script : https://pastebin.com/CrV3qHwG

steps to replicate the issue added in que above.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I could understand about your situation. In your case, it seems that the default row height is used the row height. In this case, the height can be automatically set by the texts. By this, the row height is only one row which is the height of 381000 EMU (30 pixels). So when you want to retrieve the actual height, in the current stage, I think that it is required to set the height by manual or script and retrieve the height.

Comment: @Tanaike would it be possible to ans with possible fixes ? I understand that the row min height is,  and also I have read about the EMU as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Sorry. I cannot understand about `would it be possible to ans with possible fixes ?`. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: @Tanaike OP is asking you to add a ``ans``wer.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your support. I could understand it. I would like to prepare it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your additional information, I could confirm your situation. When I saw it, I could notice that the table has one cell, and the table size is the default size. In this case, the table uses the default row height of the cell. And the height of cell is automatically set by the inputted texts. By this, the row height is only one row which is the height of 381000 EMU (30 pixels). About this situation, I confirmed that the same results were obtained from both Slides service and Slides API. So it seems that this is the current specification.

When you want to retrieve the actual height, in the current stage, I think that it is required to set the height by manual or script and retrieve the height. By this, the table is the actual row height.

Or, although this is not the completely same with the row height of the default table including the texts, I think that the row height can be also calculated using the line breaks and the font size. In this answer, I introduce the sample script for this by modifying your script.

#### Sample modification:

In order to give the height, as a sample modification, I would like to propose the following script. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

From:

```
var rowHeight = pageElements[0].asTable().getRow(0).getMinimumHeight();
```

To:

```
var t = pageElements[0].asTable().getRow(0).getCell(0).getText();
var rowHeight = (t.asString().split("\n").length - 1) * (t.getTextStyle().getFontSize() / 72 * 96);
```

- In this modification, the row height is calculated using the line breaks and the font size.

  - `t.asString().split("\n").length - 1` is the number of line breaks.
  - `t.getTextStyle().getFontSize() / 72 * 96` is the pixel value of the font size. It seems that in Google Slides, 96 DPI is used.
  - But, unfortunately, in the current stage, the result is not the completely same with the default table row height.
  - In this case, when `rowHeight` is multiplied by `1.08`, the same height is obtained. But this factor is unfounded. Please be careful this.

Comment: @Tanike , still there are more hurdles coming. Should we discuss in chat ?

Comment: Tanike your solution was working perfectly, but i found some issues when we would change the text height of any text Like I did with "Text 1", I changed the height of "Text 1", then the result of row height will be 0.0,

Comment: @Puzzled Boy Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. My additional proposal script is the script for explaining a methodology. So my sample script is a simple sample script for explaining above situation using your shared Slides. So I think that when you want to use it for various situations, it is required to modify it. I deeply apologize that my sample script cannot be used for your various situations.

Comment: @Puzzled Boy If you want to use the various font size in the cell, please retrieve each font size and retrieve the maximum font size for each line and calculate the row height. I think that the reason of issue of your new situation is this. And also, in your script, the text data is copied from the cell to the shape. So in this case, each font size is required to copy. I think that this is different from your initial question and the direction of the answer. So I proposed only the flow. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Puzzled Boy By the way, I think that your new situation might be useful for other users. If you need the sample script, how about posting it as new question by including more information of situations that you want to use? Of course, this can be decided at your discretion. By this, it will help users think of the solution. And also, I think that such question and answers will be useful for other users.

Comment: Sure I will post my another question , it required more research.

Comment: here is the updated que https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63449367/how-to-get-the-correct-height-of-table-cell-when-text-inside-the-cell