# How to get the correct height of Table cell when text inside the cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, shapes, google-slides

**History :** - [Shape size not equal to the table cell size and fit the text inside the shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63428548/shape-size-not-equal-to-the-table-cell-size-and-fit-the-text-inside-the-shape/63433855?noredirect=1#comment112185386_63433855)

Solution was working perfectly, but i found some issues when we would change the text height of any text Like I did with "**Text 1**", I changed the height of "**Text 1**", then the result of row height will be 0.0

[image]

**Limitation of Google Apps Script:**
We can't get the height of cell, can't get the padding of cell.

After some research tried to extract the cell's paragraph as text.

**Updated script with my and [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) modification :**

```
var rowHeight = 0.0;

  var tableCell = pageElements[index].asTable().getCell(ir, ic);

  //Get cell color
  let cellFill = tableCell.getFill().getSolidFill();

  var cellParaText = tableCell.getText().getParagraphs();
  cellParaText.forEach(function(item, index) {
    
    var t = cellParaText[index].getRange();

    //I tried to applied Tanaike's solution here

    rowHeight = rowHeight + ( t.asString().split("\n").length - 1 ) * ( t.getTextStyle().getFontSize() / 72 * 96 )

    //rowHeight = rowHeight + cellParaText[index].getRange().getTextStyle().getFontSize();

    rowHeight = rowHeight + cellParaText[index].getRange().getParagraphStyle().getSpaceAbove()
    rowHeight = rowHeight + cellParaText[index].getRange().getParagraphStyle().getSpaceBelow()
    rowHeight = rowHeight + (cellParaText[index].getRange().getParagraphStyle().getLineSpacing()/100)

  });


  //Get cell text, text color and text background color
  let cellText = tableCell.getText().asString()

  //insert the RECTANGLE shape 
  let insertedShape = selection.getCurrentPage()
                        .insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.RECTANGLE, cellLeft+5, cellTop+5, columnWidth, rowHeight);
```

Full script here https://pastebin.com/keXKHbhC

Here is my Table in GSlide -  https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/10nupvk-2BZDSV6-gPn_n2LkrUtkCxot7qr_jcZGBHqw/edit#slide=id.p

**Still issue is same with height of shape equal to table cell ,  See image**

[image]

Comment: I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? Unfortunately, the retrieved result is not the completely same with before conversion. So please think of that as one of several modified scripts. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

### Modification points:

- When I checked `getSpaceAbove()` and `getSpaceBelow()`, it seems that those are `0`.
- I think that `getLineSpacing()` might be used.
- And, I noticed one more important point. For example, when there are 3 paragraphs, it seems that it is required to use the spaces of 4 paragraphs.

When this points are reflected to your script of https://pastebin.com/keXKHbhC, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### From:

```
cellParaText.forEach(function(item, index) {

  var t = cellParaText[index].getRange();
  
  //i tried to applied Tanike's solution here
  rowHeight = rowHeight + ( t.asString().split("\n").length - 1 ) * ( t.getTextStyle().getFontSize() / 72 * 96 )
  
  //rowHeight = rowHeight + cellParaText[index].getRange().getTextStyle().getFontSize();
  
  rowHeight = rowHeight + cellParaText[index].getRange().getParagraphStyle().getSpaceAbove()
  rowHeight = rowHeight + cellParaText[index].getRange().getParagraphStyle().getSpaceBelow()
  rowHeight = rowHeight + (cellParaText[index].getRange().getParagraphStyle().getLineSpacing()/100)

});
```

#### To:

```
cellParaText.forEach(function(item, index, a) {
  var t = cellParaText[index].getRange();
  var lineSpace = cellParaText[index].getRange().getParagraphStyle().getLineSpacing() / 100;
  var fontSize = t.getTextStyle().getFontSize() / 72 * 96;
  rowHeight += fontSize * (a.length > 1 ? lineSpace : 1);
  if (index == a.length - 1) rowHeight += fontSize;
});
```

And also, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
insertedShape.getText()
            .getParagraphStyle()
            .setLineSpacing(cellParagraph.getLineSpacing()/100)
            .setSpaceAbove(cellParagraph.getSpaceAbove())
            .setSpaceBelow(cellParagraph.getSpaceBelow())
            .setSpacingMode(cellParagraph.getSpacingMode())
            .setParagraphAlignment(cellParagraph.getParagraphAlignment())
```

#### To:

```
insertedShape.getText()
            .getParagraphStyle()
            .setParagraphAlignment(cellParagraph.getParagraphAlignment())
```

### Result:

When your sample Google Slides is used with above modified script, it becomes as follows.

[image]

### Note:

- This is a simple sample script for your sample. So when you use other sample, the script might be required to be modified. Please be careful this.
- In this case, from your sample, it supposes that each paragraph is the same font size. Please be careful this.

Comment: Seems interesting modification, my main concern if we i will change the height of any text from paragraph. same problem comes, which we were facing in old post. but you already mentioned that "In this case, from your sample, it supposes that each paragraph is the same font size. Please be careful this." .

Comment: Is this possible we could try with font size case, " https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/10nupvk-2BZDSV6-gPn_n2LkrUtkCxot7qr_jcZGBHqw/edit#slide=id.p " .  when i make this changes in sample, that cell completely gone from result, i am trying to work on this.

Comment: @Puzzled Boy Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When you want to change the font size in the paragraph, please retrieve the maximum font size from each paragraph by retrieving every character in all paragraph. By this, the row height can be calculated.

Comment: @Puzzled Boy But in this case, please copy the each font size in each paragraph to the copied texts. And, in your case, the row height of each column is also required to be considered. By this, the texts can be correctly copied. If you want to also change the font family and so on, please copy them to the copied texts. But when you want to reflect to your current script, the major change might be required to be done. So here, I would like to propose it as a methodology for achieving your new goal. I apologize for this.

Comment: I will try same.

Comment: @Puzzled Boy Thank you for replying. If you have any issues, when you post it as new question, I think that such question and discussions will be also useful for other users.