# App Script - Get row height in a table in SlidesApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm iterating over a table with variable row sizes. Some rows cause the table to flow outside of the slide. To fix, I thought I'd set a maximum table size and add up all of the row sizes after setting the text and if it's too big create a new slide.

However, each row is always the same height. My assumption is that since it's not rendered in the UI yet, that all the rows remain the same size. I thought refreshing the slide would do it but it is not. I'm new to App Script (1 day).

```
updateRow(row, data);
slide.refreshSlide();
tableHeight += row.getMinimumHeight();
```

As an aside, I also attempted to get the size of the table using the

```
Table.getHeight()
Table.getInherentHeight()
```

methods but they continued to return null for a reason I didn't understand.

Comment: Are these threads useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63449367 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/63428548

Comment: Could you please provide a copy of the presentation you're working on, free of sensitive information, as well as the rest of code you're working on (including the code related to `updateRow`), and explain what you want to accomplish in more detail?

Comment: @Tanaike - Calculating the linebreaks and fontsize did the trick! Tremendous help. Not sure if I should answer it here or close this as duplicate. I wasn't able to find that question when I was looking for answers.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In this case, I think that this is the duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/q/63449367/7108653 as you say. But if you have the different answer, please post it as an answer. I think that by this, it will be useful for other users. If you have the same answer with the thread, we can also flag as the duplicate.